# What is Norpoth's model?

Tags: united-states

I read in online newspapers about some Norpoth's model developed by Prof. Helmut Norpoth. The model is claimed to be very accurate in predicting American Presidents given Presidential candidates, the model has correctly predicted since 1912 except 1960 election.
For me this is too much of accuracy. Does someone know how this model works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling "Norpoth model" finds http://primarymodel.com/ which says that Norpoth's model uses each party's share of the New Hampshire primary and each candidate's share of that to forecast the final result of any cross-party, two-candidate match up.

Note that there are actually two models.  From 1912-1952, the original model used the average from all primaries.  From 1956 on, the replacement used just the New Hampshire primary.  Both models are constructed the same, but they use different inputs.

Predicting presidential elections with statistical analysis is difficult because it is all too easy to engage in overfitting.  Basically overfitting means that the equation is picked to match the results.  These can be historically perfect in predictions, but lack predictive ability.  While this may be correct in some elections going forward, it is often of limited predictive capacity.

Since there are only two parties in the US, flipping a coin will be right half the time.  It's not difficult to flip a coin to match a two element pattern.  The chances are one in four.  If you have hundreds of thousands of people flipping coins, you could almost certainly find at least one who would accidentally match the actual election pattern.  If you find a hundred, about twenty-five could then flip a coin correctly two more times.  There are many prediction models.  It's not that hard to find a few that are accidentally successful.

One sign that this model has been overfitted is that it has been correct so often.  The model predicts a vote share, but the result is often within the standard error.  In those cases, it should be wrong more often than it actually has been.  That it correctly predicts the direction even in cases where it shouldn't be able to do so is a strong indication that the model's results are accidental rather than a sign of the model's effectiveness.

Results from 1912-2004 (Table 4 from the link):  [image: Norpoth primary model results from 1912-2004]

In 1960, the model simply made the wrong prediction.  The prediction was outside the standard error, but the actual result went the other way.

The [2016 prediction](https://www.sbstatesman.com/2016/02/23/political-science-professor-forecasts-trump-as-general-election-winner/) is apparently Trump over Clinton 54.7% to 45.3%.  Note that this is about the same prediction as in the Kennedy/Nixon race in 1960.

In 1976, 1980, 1988, 2000, and 2008, the prediction was much closer but the error was away from 50%.  That's too biased to be explained by the model.  The actual error should have been in the other direction half the time.  An error of the same magnitude but in the opposite direction would have changed the result of the popular vote in every one of those elections except 2000.

Note:  the table doesn't include 2008.  [Obama was forecasted](http://primarymodel.com/2008/) to win 50.1% of two-party share of the vote but actually won 53.7% (calculated from the Wikipedia data).  That's an error of about 2.6% which is also the approximate value of the standard error.

As you suggest, it is in fact too much.

Answer (score 1):

The first election this model was actually used was 1996. This professors claim about predicting every election from 1912 is not exactly a lie but it is innacurate. He used those other elections to create his model when he made his 1996 predictions.

Comment: you are not clear enough, kindly elaborate. I have not yet accepted the ans if you think you know much about the model, you can give it a try. welcome to politics.SE